# Can a list with $\mathcal{O}(1)$ access have an insertion complexity better than $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Tags: time-complexity, lists

It seems intuitive that there's no list data structure which has $\mathcal{O}(1)$  worst case time complexity for random access and a worst case complexity better than $\mathcal{O}(n)$ for insertion: if insertion is allowed to affect only a *small part* of the list, then there's no way for it to always keep the *entire list* in a structure that allows for constant time element access.

Is there any proof (or counterexample) of this?

Comment: When you say "insertion", what do you mean? Insertion at a specific index?

Comment: @orlp Yes, insertion at a specific index.

Comment: In which computation model? This is important, because in real world if you keep connecting more and more memory to your computer (as big-Oh assumes), you can't expect constant-time random access to the memory.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz If you don't allow constant-time random access, you're just never gonna get _O(1)_ here, so that's a bit ridiculous.  Of course OP assumes random access.

Comment: Do you have to have _O(1)_ worst case, or is _O(1)_ amortized acceptable?

Comment: @PålGD sure. But what else are we to assume? Is the question about PRAM? Is it about cell-probe model? Is it about TM with random-access tape?

Comment: You're completely right, but I would assume that to be part of an answer.  In this and that model, we know that this and that, in the other model blah-di-blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have both as fast as possible random access and faster-than-full-rebuild insertion time.

I assume you know how dynamically growing arrays work. Also, I assume you know how to make them work in $O(1)$ worst-case. These techniques allow us to focus on the problem for lists of limited size only.

Let $n$ be the maximal size (capacity) of the list. Let’s divide the list into $O(\sqrt{n})$ blocks of equal size $B$ (which is $O(\sqrt{n})$ too). Let also $b_j$ denote a cyclic shift of the $j$-th block.

When you need to **access** $i$-th element of the list, you calculate its position as follows in $O(1)$:

$$f(i) = (b_j + i \mod B) + B \times j$$

where $j = \lfloor \frac{i}{B} \rfloor$.

When you need to **insert** something into $i$-th position, you first make a cyclic shift of everything from $j$-th block to the end:

1. Decrement all $b$ values starting from $j$.
2. Swap the elements on the boundaries of consequtive blocks, so that every element is in its right place.
3. Then you fix $j$-th block by rebuilding it from scratch.

This gives you $O(\sqrt{n})$ insertion complexity.

Answer (score -1):

As accessing to an element is in $O(1)$, it would be something like an array. And, if this assumption is true, your discussion would be near the concept of "Dynamic Array". It's insertion to the array is $O(1)$ and amortized **cost of $n$ insertion** to the data structure is $O(n)$. 
It might be helpful for what you want to reach.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and don't know who did, but inserting into the beginning or to the middle in a dynamic array is _O(n)_.  Inserting at end is amortized _O(1)_.  I think OP wanted arbitrary insert to be (amortized?) _O(1)_.